# My file exists though fileExistsAtPath always returns false

Tags: ios, swift, nsfilemanager, file-exists

I'm using the following code to detect if a file exists. The file does exist but fileExistsAtPath always returns false

```
 if let receiptFound = receiptUrl?.checkResourceIsReachableAndReturnError(error){
        print("receiptUrl is \(receiptUrl?.path)") }

 print("Does the file exist \(NSFileManager.defaultManager().fileExistsAtPath(receiptUrl!.path!))")

    if NSFileManager.defaultManager().fileExistsAtPath(receiptUrl!.path!)


    {  //work with file
    }
```

My output is:

[image]

I can't understand why the statement is returned as false when the file exists?

Comment: Can you debug to see the urlPath, I guess the the URL path might be nil or not correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks to me like the URL you are messing with is outside of the app sandbox.

Your app only has access to a very limited number of directories (parts of the app bundle, documents, caches, and a few other folders). The file manager probably doesn't have any access to the StoreKit directory, and so the function `fileExistsAtPath` returns false.

### EDIT

Note that the beginning of your path is `/private`. That's a strong indication that the file is NOT accessible to a third party app like yours.

Comment: Thanks Duncan, that poses a challenge for me then because I'm trying to extract the data from the receipt to verify it but if I don't have access to the StoreKit directory then that could be challenging.

Comment: Likely impossible on a non-jailbroken iOS device